# how can I make dictionary with two lists in number of all cases?

Tags: python

I want to make dictionary with two lists but want to make dictionary in all cases. for example,

```
list1 = [a,b,c]
list2 = [up,down]


# output
dic1 = [a:up, b:up, c:up]
dic2 = [a:down, b:up, c:up]
dic3 = [a:up, b:down, c:up]
.
.
.
```

I know how to make one dictionary output with zip, but it is hard to find making dictionary to all number of cases.

Comment: what is the use of doing this? can you explain the use case so there may be a other better solution.

Comment: @Vignesh thanks for the comment. I am making some investing program and have to make all cases of mongodb queries  so that I can find best investment strategy. For example, there are many keys such as "rsi", "macd", "stochestic" which has different values like "up". "down". I want to check which combination is the best but key-value is too many to make all the different combination by my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```
import itertools
list1=['a','b','c']
list2=['Up','Down']

ListofDict = [dict(zip(x,list2)) for x in itertools.permutations(list1,len(list2))]

for _ in ListofDict:
    print(_)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'Up', 'b': 'Down'}
{'a': 'Up', 'c': 'Down'}
{'a': 'Down', 'b': 'Up'}
{'b': 'Up', 'c': 'Down'}
{'a': 'Down', 'c': 'Up'}
{'c': 'Up', 'b': 'Down'}
```

Comment: thank you! and I just found itertools product also do such a thing. :)